# How To Get Two JS/Jquery Plugins to Work Together?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plugins

I've posted here before but can't find my account so this is my new first post.

I'm attempting to use a js plugin called "blueberry slider" with a responsive js menu called "Menumaker" and something is conflicting, can't get the slider to show. I really don't know what I'm doing with JS yet, hoping someone can help. In Chrome, element inspection, it's saying "undefined is not a function". I haven't modified anything of the plugins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem is probably that you're loading a version of jquery, adding a plugin to it, and then loading a new version of jquery and attempting to add a plugin to that, too. Pick a single version of jquery to include. You're including three:

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

at the top,

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

just above your blueberry script, and

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.8.3.min.js"></script>
```

at the bottom just above your menumaker script.

The latest version of jQuery loads and overwrites your blueberry script's modified version of jQuery.

I suggest you just get rid of the last two and use the first version.

Answer (score 0):

the function which you are calling and function present in your plugin library doesn't match , which is the reason it doesn't find any function named "undefined" in that library. Try checking the function name in it's documentation.